# How to center an SVG image without shrinking the width

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries

Inside my three blocks, I have an svg image, but I have it like this:

```
.rating {
text-align: center;
background-color: var(--light-grayish-magenta);
color: var(--very-dark-magenta);
font-weight: 700;
border-radius: 7px;
max-width: 26em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.rating::before {
content: '';
width: 5.625em;
height: 1em;
display: block;
background-image: url(images/icon-star.svg);
background-repeat: space;
}
```

And I have a @media query set.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 21.885em) /* breakpoint 350px phones ---> tablets */ {
.status {
    max-width: 20em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
    .rating {
    padding: 0.9em;
}
    .rating::before {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="status flow-content">
        <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</div>
        <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</div>
        <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</div>
    </div>
```

Though when the screen shrinks so does the image and it sort of flips from side to side. I tried margins left, right, displays can't figure it out though.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to replicate the issue you are having with the code you provided. I did however manage to center align the stars and it was being more friendly that way. Try adding the following to '.rating::before' in your CSS elements.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```